# Visual C++ versions of GCC functions

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, g++

Are there Visual C++ versions of the following (in GCC)?

1. `__builtin_return_address`
2. `__builtin_frame_address`

Reference - http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html

If not, is there a way to emulate them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a full list of the available [Visual Studio 2008 Compiler Intrinsics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26td21ds.aspx). One of the ones you are specifically looking for here is [_ReturnAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64ez38eh.aspx)... still looking for the other.

For walking the stack (and getting frame pointers), read the details on the [Visual Leak Detector stack walking mechanism](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/visualleakdetector.aspx#source), which uses [StackWalk64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680650%28VS.85%29.aspx) internally.

Answer (score 1):

For functions declared `__cdecl`, the frame address is the top of the function's stack (pointed to by `esp`, and adjusted by the `sizeof` the function's parameters). I believe GCC typically stores that pointer for the current function in `ebp` (not sure about VS). That memory location is a pointer, and holds the return address.

For functions declared `__fastcall`, the adjustment to `esp` is much smaller, as some of the function's arguments *may* have been passed in registers.

I'm not sure about `__stdcall`, but I *think* it's the same as `__cdecl`.

Comment: Deduction. The run-time solution is to trace back and simulate popping the stack to locate the old stack locations.

Answer (score 1):

The corresponding function to __builtin_frame_address, if it exists, would likely not work in optimized code, since VC does an optimization called Frame Pointer Omission.  However, you can turn that optimization off, as described here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kxx5t2c(VS.71).aspx

Note that, for x86 you can write inline assembly code
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ks26t93(VS.71).aspx
unfortunately, it doesn't work for 64-bit architectures so that probably isn't helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [_AddressOfReturnAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s975zw7k%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to determine frame address.